# Flex Spark Textinput prevents component to be collected by GC

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4, flex-spark

I've got a custom component (quite complex so I can't post any code here, although that shouldn't matter), that I can add to a view. When the component is deleted from the view or the view is switched I call my own dispose method which removes remaining eventListeners and kills some references so that the component can eventually be nulled and collected by the GC.

All that works perfectly fine until I add a Spark TextInput to the MXML part of the component (it took me hours to find out what is preventing the component to be collected!), so I recon that the TextInput somehow automatically adds some eventListeners.

My question is what are these listeners, or is there anything else I haven't thought of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try using the `hasEventListener()` method to determine which listeners aren't being removed, if any. Look in the source code of SkinnableTextBase to see which listeners are added internally.

Comment: Thanks so much RIAstar. There are indeed two listeners that aren't removed (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN and TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_START). I'm wondering why Adobe didn't use (at least) weak references when adding them in the first place. Anyway, is there a quick way to remove those listeners from within my component? I can't access the listener function of TextBase from within my component and I'd like to avoid extending it and making my own TextInput just to override and then be able to access those listener function in order to remove them.

Comment: Look at the `styleChanged()` method: it would seem that if you set the TextInput's `interactionMode` style to `InteractionMode.MOUSE`, that would remove the listeners.

Comment: Ah crap, totally didn't see that. Works as expected. ;) Thank you very much! You might wanna add your comments as a formal answer here so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize our discussion for the pleasure of future readers.

**Find the culprit**

You could can have a look at the code of [SkinnableTextBase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html) to see what event listeners are attached internally. Now that you know that, you can use [hasEventListener()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html#hasEventListener%28%29) to test which ones weren't removed. Using this technique we found that these listeners were still lingering:

- MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
- TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_START

**Removing them** (preferably without subclassing TextInput)

Have a look at the code of SkinnableTextBase where these listeners are registered:

```
override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void
{
    super.styleChanged(styleProp);

    if (!styleProp ||
        styleProp == "styleName" || styleProp == "interactionMode")
    {
        if (getStyle("interactionMode") == InteractionMode.TOUCH && !touchHandlersAdded)
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, touchMouseDownHandler);
            addEventListener(TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_START,
                touchInteractionStartHandler);
            touchHandlersAdded = true;
        }
        else if (getStyle("interactionMode") == InteractionMode.MOUSE && touchHandlersAdded)
        {
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, touchMouseDownHandler);
            removeEventListener(TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_START,
                touchInteractionStartHandler);
            touchHandlersAdded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This means that if you set the TextInput's `interactionMode` style to `InteractionMode.MOUSE`, that should remove the listeners.

---

Note: you might want to take a look at the [JIRA bug base](https://bugs.adobe.com/flex/) and file a bug if noone already has. Though I must say I'm not sure if this JIRA is still maintained now that Flex is moving to Apache.